# How to make grails documentation

Tags: grails, documentation

How to use Grails documentation Engine?
I want to use it, but there is no hints/tips/guides or anything about using, it. 
Just the "grails-doc" source files, that do not show clearly how change templates, or about the build process.
Are anyone using it? Or at least know how to do this to give some line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a rails user and in rails we use **rake doc:rails** . I don't know about grails but I found some links which may help you: 
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/doc.html, http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#docengine

Comment: ok thanks for reference, but i want to know, how to generate the doc? is automatic or manual generate? thanks

Comment: okay, i get good tutorial from http://www.christianoestreich.com/2012/02/grails-script-docs-helper/, thanks anyway